# Un proverbio per "la parte più debole sarà sempre perdente"

Tags: proverbs

Sto cercando un proverbio italiano che significa "la parte più debole sarà sempre perdente".

Background: Ho avuto una discussione seria con il mio capo al lavoro. Quando arrivo a casa ho detto a mio padre quello che è successo, e lui ha detto: "Non avresti dovuto farlo. La parte più debole sarà sempre perdente".  Nella mia lingua madre si dice che "la corda si rompe sempre sul lato più debole". C'è qualche proverbio simile in italiano?

Comment: Intendi “dovrà sempre perdere”? Così non è italiano...

Comment: boh! forse 'ubi maior, minor cessat' (o qualcosa di simile)

Comment: Credo che la frase originale fosse "La parte più debole sarà sempre perdente". Non mi vengono in mente proverbi simili, ma  'ubi maior, minor cessat' ha un significato diverso, per cui mi sembra non corretto.
Piuttosto mi viene in mente l'aforisma "La ragione del più forte è sempre la migliore."

Comment: Vedo che hai fatto una domanda simile in inglese (poco più di 2 anni fa): https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/212626/is-there-a-saying-or-proverb-for-a-situation-where-the-weakest-party-will-always/212766

Comment: *Se sei martello batti, se sei incudine statti*... secondo me si avvicina abbastanza.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"A muro basso ognuno ci si appoggia"
("if a wall is low, everybody leans on it")

Comment: Could you please explain the meaning and use of this proverb? Because I think it may have a similar sense, but it's not exactly the same thing (it's really difficult to find a proverb in a language which is the "exact translation" of a proverb in another language).

Answer (score 2):

> Chi pecora si fa lupo s' 'o magna.

Potete trovare questo proverbio con le sue diverse varianti dialettali sul [*Dizionario dei proverbi italiani e dialettali*](https://books.google.es/books?id=vXlfAQAAQBAJ&pg=PT118&dq=Chi+pecora+si+fa+lupo+magna&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjLicP06P71AhW6gs4BHWC9AYMQ6AF6BAgCEAE#v=onepage&q=Chi%20pecora%20si%20fa%20lupo%20magna&f=false) di
Riccardo Schwamenthal e Michele L. Straniero.

Comment: Condivido la risposta, ma come mai hai messo una delle versioni dialettali anziché quella in italiano standard?

Answer (score 1):

La descrizione che fai mi fa venire in mente l'espressione:

> - ***[l'anello debole](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/A/anello.shtml)***:  persona, organismo che, in un sistema, è in posizione di svantaggio.

In pratica tuo padre sta dicendo che hai sbagliato a discutere   con il tuo capo in quanto tu sei un anello debole (quindi hai solo da perdere) all'interno della tua organizzazione,

(Sabatini Coletti)

Comment: Io non ho mai usato questa espressione in questo senso. Per me l'anello debole è visto dal punto di vista della catena, quindi nel senso che l'intera catena è a rischio se un solo anello è debole. Dunque l'anello debole è da proteggere. Invece il senso chiesto dall'OP è proprio quello di una posizione di debolezza proprio in virtù del fatto di non avere protezione. Io piuttosto direi *l'ultima ruota del carro*, anche se pure questa è usata in un senso leggermente diverso.

Answer (score 1):

Non tecnicamente un proverbio, ma si potrebbe dire che sei un [vaso di coccio tra vasi di ferro](https://www.dizionario-italiano.it/linguamadre/articolo.php?art=835).